# Loop through files with extension also takes the next letters

Tags: batch-file, command-line

For example, instead of get only .mid files, i get also .midi file and i want avoid this:

[image]

If possible, I would like to avoid using an If condition in the DO statement.
I need to use this simple for loop because it doesn't cycle in the subfolders and it's the behavior I want.

Comment: `midi` files have a shortname of `.mid`. So they will match a filespec of `*.mid`. Just add a check `for %i in (*.mid) do @if not %~xi=.midi Echo %i`.

Comment: Please post your command line as well as your text output as text rather than as an image by [edit]ing your post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, most commands treat `*.ext` as any extension beginning with `.ext` so as you've seen, that would include, `*.extn` too:

You can therefore change that first line at the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) to either:

```dos
FOR %i IN ('Dir /B/A-D *.mid^|FindStr /IEC:".mid"') DO @ECHO %~nxi
```

Or:

```dos
FOR %i IN ("*.mid") DO @IF /I "%~xi"  == ".mid" ECHO %~nxi
```

You could also use a command which treats the extension properly, **`where.exe`**:

```dos
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %A In ('Where .:*.mid 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %~nxA
```

*From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) you'd double up the **`%`** characters.*

Comment: FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('where *.mid') DO @ECHO %~nxi

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=*" %i IN ('where *.mid') DO @ECHO %~nxi

Comment: It's not the same, if you don't use **`.`** as the current directory, it will search elsewhere, _(in the directories listed under `%PATH%`)_. It just so happens that you currently don't have any `.mid` files in them, _hence not seeing the difference_.

Comment: "Open a command prompt window, CD to "%UserProfile%\Desktop" and then enter, CD.>test dll, (this will create an empty test.dll file on your desktop). Now enter Where .:*.dll, and note the output, now do the same but using Where *.dll. The only way you would have matching output would be if, you didn't have the default entries in your %PATH%."

WTF! :-O you are right! Strange behaviour.

Comment: why is it necessary to specify the EOL option?

Comment: After a full day of tests I finally discovered that the solution in your answer is the best: For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %A In ('Where .:*.mid 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %~nxA

Comment: In this specific case, it shouldn't be necessary to stipulate an `EOL`, it's more a habit. Generally, a `For` loop, uses a default `EOL` of a semicolon, **`;`**, this means that any returned string beginning with one is excluded from the output. `Where` however, outputs the resultant strings as full file paths, meaning that everything should begin with a letter, `A`-`Z`. So you could just use `"Delims="` instead. You could try `"Tokens=*"`, and it should perform equally as well in this case, as all strings will also not end with a space or tab, _(they'll all end with `.mid`)_.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f %i in ( ' dir /b *.mid^|findstr /e /i /L /c:".mid" ' ) do @echo %i
```

not simple, but avoids the `if` statement. A simple `dir` filtered by `findstr` to find lines that `/e` end with `/i` case-insensitive, `/L` literal `/c:` constant string.

"doesn't even" implies that you actually want to scan subdirectories. To do that, add the `/s` switch to the `dir` command. Also might be advisable to add `/on` to the `dir` command to cater for FAT filesystems.

Comment: I need to use this simple for loop because it doesn't cycle in the subfolders and it's the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %i IN ('WHERE .:*.mid 2^> NUL') DO @ECHO %~nxi
```

For more files:

```
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %i IN ('WHERE .:*.mid .:*.midi 2^> NUL') DO @ECHO %~nxi
```

Or (equivalent syntax)

```
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %i IN ('WHERE "%CD%:*.mid" "%CD%:*.midi" 2^> NUL') DO @ECHO %~nxi
```

For more files and path:

```
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %i IN ('WHERE "%Path1%:*.exe" "%Path2%:*.dll" 2^> NUL') DO @ECHO %~nxi
```

%CD% or . means "Current directory" but:
%CD% cause an error for paths with spaces, then in this case it must be enclosed in double quotes.
. is good also for path with spaces.

In these examples, searching for files in directories is not recursive.

Comment: You didn't ask for a recursive function in your question, so including it in your answer wasn't necessary, _especially given your comment below Magoo's answer_. Additionally, as I commented in response to you under my answer, ignoring the **`.`**, as the current directory is not wise, _please try it with a single `.dll` file in your current directory, if you don't believe me_. Essentially adding your answer, has benefited nobody, and taken focus away from my already accepted answer.

Comment: In "C:\Windows" i have tryed with an file in the subfolder "System32" and was not found: WHERE acproxy.dll. Instead was found with: WHERE /R . acproxy.dll. I use Windows 7.

Comment: In any case, your advice to use the where.exe program is brilliant and makes the code much more streamlined. Thank you very much.

Comment: Open a command prompt window, `CD` to `"%UserProfile%\Desktop"` and then enter, `CD.>test dll`, _(this will create an empty `test.dll` file on your desktop)_. Now enter `Where .:*.dll`, and note the output, now do the same but using `Where *.dll`. The only way you would have matching output would be if, you didn't have the default entries in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: TBF, if you read the output from the command help, `where /?`, _if my memory serves_, it should stipulate that behaviour, _(current directory and those within PATH)_, as it's default search locations. Obviously stipulating a directory, means that the default is no longer used.

Comment: "TBF, if you read the output from the command help, where /?, if my memory serves, it should stipulate that behaviour, (current directory and those within PATH), as it's default search locations. Obviously stipulating a directory, means that the default is no longer used.". I have read help, you are right! Thank you for all!